# How to compute a definite integral in a Lubin-Tate extension of a local field?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

In [*class field theory* by **Neukirch**](http://books.google.com.tw/books/about/Class_Field_Theory.html?id=Wap8MQEACAAJ&redir_esc=y), one finds the following definition:

> $$\eta_{L\mid K}(s):=\int_0^s\frac{dx}{(G_0:G_x)}.$$

In the paragraghs following the definition, one finds a proposition:

> $$\eta_{L\mid K}(s)=\frac{1}{g_0}\sum_{\sigma\in G}(\text{min}(i_{L\mid K}(\sigma),s+1)-1),$$

where $g_i:=\mid G_i\mid$, and where $G_i$ are higher ramification groups.
Then one finds the statement that, in the Lubin-Tate $\pi ^m$ -th division field extension of local fields $L_m\mid K$, we have:

> > $$\eta_{L_m\mid K}(q^n-1)=n, n=0,\ldots m-1$$

where $q$ is the residue class field order of $K$.
I have tried to use the above-mentioned formulae and definition to compute this integral, but I failed to see why this is true.
So any hint or any solution is sincerely thanked.

Comment: Would the down-voter care to explain the reason in voting down? Or at least leave a comment, telling me where I can improve upon? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I find a hint in [*Algebraic Number Theory* by **Neukirch.**](http://www.amazon.com/Algebraic-Number-Grundlehren-mathematischen-Wissenschaften/dp/3540653996) It states that $\eta_{L|K}(q^n-1)=\frac{g_1+\ldots+g_{q^n-1}}{g_0}$, with $g_i=(q^{m-1}-q^{n-1})(q-1),$ for $q^{n-1}\leq i\leq q^n-1$. But I still fail to perceive why the formula in question holds. Hope this helps in finding an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally formed an attempt in proving the claim.
As mentioned in the above comment, it grows out of a hint in another book by **Neukirch**, *Algebraic Number Theory*.
Firstly, the formula in that book is wrong: it should be $g_i=q^{m-n}$, for $q^{n-1}\leq i\leq q^n-1$, so that the sum over all such $i$ is $q^{m-n}(q^n-q^{n-1})=q^{m-1}(q-1)$. While it is well-known that, for a Lubin-Tate extension $L_m$, it is purely ramified of degree $q^{m-1}(q-1)$. Since it is purely ramified, by elementary algebraic number theory we know that the inertia group $G_0$ has order =$e_{L_m|K}=[L:K]$. Thus the result follows naturally.
Inform me of any error that disdains this argument. Thanks very much.